# Should have I rejected this edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, review, suggested-edits

About: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2193818

The edit in question has an edit summary of 'broken link'. Looking at the markdown, I can see that what the suggester did was just remove the broken link altogether.

I was thinking about rejecting as too minor or invalid, but then I saw that the post is really popular - ~180 up votes.

Surely, I though, no post that popular should have a broken link. And so I accepted.

Now, however, I am wondering what I should have done. Accepted because it does *fix* the post, or reject because it was probably the author's job to fix the link.

What do you think?

Comment: Looked okay to me.

Comment: General Test in these situations is to ask yourself if you would have made the edit yourself. If you answer "Yes", then Approve it. If you answer "No", then Reject it. If you don't know and are not sure of the situation, then you should Skip the Review. (Just saying so that it might help you Review well in future).

Comment: @Adi Thanks! Good guideline.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was only a link to a sample implementation, and there are 3 other links left.

The post can stand fine without that link, there is no alternative link at the moment to replace it, so yes, it was fine you approved it.