# Is it relevant that the Suggested Edit comes from the OP?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

There's a certain type of code edit that I recognize as those that usually come from the OP. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3170349).

In these cases the OP is trying to ensure that the answer for their question is perfect. Sometimes these code edits are accepted but often they are rejected.

Is it:

- okay to consider who is making the edit when deciding whether to approve it, and to give *weight* to the fact that it's coming from the OP? The UI doesn't give any indication that the suggested edit is coming from the OP so I'm guessing the answer is no.
- If the edit isn't approved what should one do when one sees an OP trying to correct an almost-perfect answer?

Should one:

- leave a comment for the OP
- suggest they self-answer (this doesn't seem to make sense, often the answer the OP is trying to edit has the green check-mark)
- make the edit on the OP's behalf
- do something else (ignore it?)

Comment: I think this comment applies here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181854/should-have-i-rejected-this-edit#comment553294_181854

Comment: I don't feel confident enough that this is the right answer, but I think the measuring stick here is why is it being changed.  Is it actually a "bug" or a syntax error and the fix is necessary to let the code work for the question... then it is ok.  If the edit is just adding more code (not fixing the existing code) especially code beyond the scope of the answer, then it is not ok.

Comment: But in general, no, it shouldn't matter who is making the edit.  If it is good, approve it, if it isn't don't.  But I wouldn't make the edit yourself unless you are comfortable enough to attach your name to the edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What should one do when one sees an [editor] trying to correct an almost-perfect answer?

Approve it. It doesn't matter whether the edit was suggested by the asker or not. Correcting an almost-perfect answer is encouraged.

The only way in which it is relevant that the edit comes from the asker is that it gives you more confidence in the correctness of the suggestion (especially when the asker also accepted the answer). This is what someone tried and found to work. This isn't to say that you should take all edits from the asker at face value, of course — sometimes the asker misunderstood the answer and tried something different that the answerer never intended. Always use your judgement, and skip if unsure.